# Port forwarding in ubuntu server 17.10

Tags: networking, server, port-forwarding

i recently installed [nextcloud](https://nextcloud.com/) on my ubuntu server for accessing it outside the my local network i need to do port forwarding from localhost to external ip on port no. 443
i tired this solution
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/182421/forwarding-a-localhostport-to-an-externalipnewport .when i checked i'm still getting port closed. i enable port forwarding in my router also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your router's settings if your WAN IP is different from your public IP, then it is possible that your router is behind another router i.e., your ISP use [CGN (Carrier-grade NAT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT). Look at this also [RFC6598](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6598).

If this is the case, then this link may help you

1. [how to do port forwarding if my router wan ip is different from public ip?](https://superuser.com/questions/1035938/how-to-do-port-forwarding-if-my-router-wan-ip-is-different-from-public-ip)